# QGIS: export map images centered on a series of GPS coordinates

Tags: qgis, animation

I am hoping to create an animated video based on a QGIS map I have created. The Time Manager plugin looks like a close match, but I'm not sure if it will be able to do what I'm looking for:

Instead of a layer being animated on top of static map, I'd like the map itself to pan following a route generated by Google Maps.

I am imagining a scenario where I would import a path of Lat/Long coordinates, choose a fixed scale to "photograph" from, and then automatically export images along the path centered on each of the coordinates. Some kind of sequential file naming would then make it easier to import into an animation software program.

Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first convert the coordinates (not sure what data format these are in (.csv)) into a point layer based on the lat/lng and then use the QGIS Composer atlas to export each point location out as an image.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like just the thing I need. I'll give it a try and we'll see how it like processing 1000+ data points...

Answer (score 1):

The technique given by artwork21 did the trick - I was able to use the atlas generator to export a series of frames that could be re-assembled with ffmpeg into an animated video. I think it turned out ok:

[Wakefield to Winnipeg #2 on Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/240747515)